# ssh to single host from multiple users

Tags: ssh, localhost, remote-host

I have already successfully set up an automatic ssh connection to a remote host on my (Mac) laptop (`ssh-keygen`, `ssh-copy-id` of the public key on the .ssh folder on the host machine, inserted the password once and now connects automatically). I would like to be able to do the same from the (Ubuntun 12) machine I use at work.
Here's what I did:
used `ssh-keygen` again, this time calling the keys id_rsa2 (differently from my laptop's which is the standard `id_rsa`)
and here come's the problem:
if I try to `ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa2.pub user@hostname:/.ssh/`
I get:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname hostename:/.ssh: Name or service not known
```

but if I try to `ssh user@hostmane`, I am prompted to insert the password and it connects without problems. Any clue someone? thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should drop the `:/.ssh/` from the end of your hostname:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa2.pub user@hostname
```

Comment: [SOLVED] Thank you very much. now I can automatically ssh from both my laptop and my machine at work

Comment: Cool. Glad to hear it. Can you accept the answer by clicking the check-mark next to this answer? See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work